# streaming XML serialization in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, streaming

I'm trying to serialize a very large `IEnumerable<MyObject>` using an `XmlSerializer` without keeping all the objects in memory.

The `IEnumerable<MyObject>` is actually lazy..

I'm looking for a streaming solution that will:

1. Take an object from the `IEnumerable<MyObject>`
   Serialize it to the underlying stream using the standard serialization (*I don't want to handcraft the XML here!*)
2. Discard the in memory data and move to the next

I'm trying with this code:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
 var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
  foreach (var myObject in myObjectsIEnumerable)
  {
   xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, myObject);
  }
}
```

but I'm getting multiple XML headers and I cannot specify a root tag `<MyObjects>` so my XML is invalid.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingXmlSerializersWithXElementsAndLINQToXML.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `XmlWriter` class is a fast streaming API for XML generation. It is rather low-level, MSDN has an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) on instantiating a validating XmlWriter using `XmlWriter.Create()`.

Edit: link fixed. Here is sample code from the article:

```
async Task TestWriter(Stream stream) 
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Async = true;

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)) {
        await writer.WriteStartElementAsync("pf", "root", "http://ns");
        await writer.WriteStartElementAsync(null, "sub", null);
        await writer.WriteAttributeStringAsync(null, "att", null, "val");
        await writer.WriteStringAsync("text");
        await writer.WriteEndElementAsync();
        await writer.WriteCommentAsync("cValue");
        await writer.WriteCDataAsync("cdata value");
        await writer.WriteEndElementAsync();
        await writer.FlushAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: The link is broken. Pity that the answer didn't contain the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the notice @Rob, link fixed and code from the article copied to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Utils
{
    public class XMLSerializer
    {
        public static Byte[] StringToUTF8ByteArray(String xmlString)
        {
            return new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(xmlString);
        }

        public static String SerializeToXML<T>(T objectToSerialize)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            XmlWriterSettings settings = 
                new XmlWriterSettings {Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true};

            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings))
            {
                if (xmlWriter != null)
                {
                    new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(xmlWriter, objectToSerialize);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static void DeserializeFromXML<T>(string xmlString, out T deserializedObject) where T : class
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(StringToUTF8ByteArray(xmlString)))
            {
                deserializedObject = xs.Deserialize(memoryStream) as T;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call:

```
string xml = Utils.SerializeToXML(myObjectsIEnumerable);
```

I haven't tried it with, for example, an `IEnumerable` that fetches objects one at a time remotely, or any other weird use cases, but it works perfectly for `List<T>` and other collections that are in memory.

**EDIT**: Based on your comments in response to this, you could use `XmlDocument.LoadXml` to load the resulting XML string into an `XmlDocument`, save the first one to a file, and use that as your master XML file. For each item in the `IEnumerable`, use `LoadXml` again to create a new in-memory `XmlDocument`, grab the nodes you want, append them to the master document, and save it again, getting rid of the new one.

After you're finished, there may be a way to wrap all of the nodes in your root tag. You could also use XSL and `XslCompiledTransform` to write another XML file with the objects properly wrapped in the root tag.

Comment: The problem here is that I don't want to keep all the objects or the whole XML doc / string in memory. I really want to serialize one object at a time and append to a FileStream the XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by implementing the `IXmlSerializable` interface on the large class. The implementation of the `WriteXml` method can write the start tag, then simply loop over the `IEnumerable<MyObject>` and serialize each `MyObject` to the same `XmlWriter`, one at a time.

In this implementation, there won't *be* any in-memory data to get rid of (past what the garbage collector will collect).