# How to fetch,process and save huge record set in c# efficiently?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to achieve below things:

- get the data from SQL DB .
- Pass data to PerformStuff method which has third party method
  MethodforResponse(It checks input and provide repsonse)
- Save response(xml) back to SQL DB.

below is the sample code.performance wise its not good ,if there are 1000,000 Records in DB its very slow.

its there a better of doing it?any idea or hints to make it better.

please help.

```
using thirdpartylib;
 public class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var response = PerformStuff();
            Save(response);


        }

        public class TestRequest
        {
            public int col1 { get; set; }
            public bool col2 { get; set; }
            public string col3 { get; set; }
            public bool col4 { get; set; }

            public string col5 { get; set; }
            public bool col6 { get; set; }
            public string col7 { get; set; }

        }
        public class TestResponse
        {
            public int col1 { get; set; }
            public string col2 { get; set; }
            public string col3 { get; set; }
            public int col4 { get; set; }

        }
        public TestRequest GetDataId(int id)
        {
            TestRequest testReq = null;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = DB.GetSqlCommand("proc_name");
                cmd.AddInSqlParam("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, id);
                SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader(DB.GetDataReader(cmd));
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    testReq = new TestRequest();

                    testReq.col1 = dr.GetInt32("col1");
                    testReq.col2 = dr.GetBoolean("col2");
                    testReq.col3 = dr.GetString("col3");
                    testReq.col4 = dr.GetBoolean("col4");
                    testReq.col5 = dr.GetString("col5");
                    testReq.col6 = dr.GetBoolean("col6");
                    testReq.col7 = dr.GetString("col7");



                }
                dr.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return testReq;

        }
        public static TestResponse PerformStuff()
        {
            var response = new TestResponse();
            //give ids in list
            var ids = thirdpartylib.Methodforid()


            foreach (int id in ids)
            {

                var request = GetDataId(id);


                var output = thirdpartylib.MethodforResponse(request);

                foreach (var data in output.Elements())
                {
                    response.col4 = Convert.ToInt32(data.Id().Class());
                    response.col2 = data.Id().Name().ToString();

                }
            }
            //request details
            response.col1 = request.col1;
            response.col2 = request.col2;
            response.col3 = request.col3;

            return response;
        }

        public static void Save(TestResponse response)
        {

            var Sb = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                Sb.Append("<ROOT>");
                Sb.Append("<id");
                Sb.Append(" col1='" + response.col1 + "'");
                Sb.Append(" col2='" + response.col2 + "'");
                Sb.Append(" col3='" + response.col3 + "'");
                Sb.Append(" col4='" + response.col4 + "'");

                Sb.Append("></Id>");
                Sb.Append("</ROOT>");
                var cmd = DB.GetSqlCommand("saveproc");
                cmd.AddInSqlParam("@Data", SqlDbType.VarChar, Sb.ToString());
                DB.ExecuteNoQuery(cmd);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary to save XML into DB?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan ,actually its not.

Comment: I would suggest to split up the records in smaller chunks. Stored procedure should emit only a subset and offer the client to implement some kind of paging. As example the client could request records from a pafticular range (0 to 500). In a second resultset the procedure can tell the caller how many records are still left.

Comment: Only way I can think of speed thing up is if the third party function would accept multiple requests object per invocation.  Otherwise you are stuck with sequential operation.  You could try to spawn multiple worker threads  so multiple records may be processed concurrently.

Comment: From reading your sample code, it looks like you read many records and write just one. Your PerformStuff method gets called once and returns just one TestResponse method.  Is that true?

Comment: @Leng.. yes it also accepts List<request>

Comment: @jones .. yes it's true

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and the method `PerformStuff()` will be fundamentally slow because it takes `O(n) * db_lookup_time` before another iteration of the output. So, to me it seems you're going about this problem the wrong way.

Database query languages are made to optimize data traversal. So iterating by id, and then checking values, goes around this producing **the slowest lookup time** possible.

**Instead**, leverage SQL's powerful query language and use clauses like `where id < 10 and value > 100` because you **ultimately want to limit the size of the data set** needed to be processed by C#.

**So:**

1. Read *just* the *smallest* amount data you need from the DB
2. Process this data as a unit, parallelism *might* help.
3. Write back modifications in one DB connection.

Hope this sets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your problem is that you get and insert data record-by-record.  There is no possible way to optimize it.  You need to change the approach in general.

You should think of a solution that:
1. Gets all the data in one command to the database.
2. Process it.
3. Save it back to the database in one command, using a technique like [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  Please be ware that BULK INSERT has certain limitations, so read the documentation carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, there are multiple things you can enhance in your solution, from memory consumption to CPU usage.

1. Take advantage of [paging](https://www.sqlshack.com/introduction-pagination-sql-server/)) at the database level. Do not fetch all records at once, to avoid having memory leaks and/or high memory consumption in cases of 1+ million records, rather take chunk by chunk and do whatever you need to do with it.
2. Since you don't need to save XML into a database, you can choose to save response into the file. Saving XML into file gives you an opportunity to [stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2) data onto your local disc.
3. Instead of assembling XML by yourself, use [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.7.2) to do that job for you. XmlSerializer works nicely with [XmlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) which in the end can work with any [stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netframework-4.7.2) including `FileStream`. There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721537/streaming-xml-serialization-in-net) about it, which you can take as an example.

To conclude, `PerformStuff` method won't be only faster, but it will require way fewer resources (memory, CPU) and the most important thing, you'll be easily able to constraint resource consumption of your program (by changing the size of database page).

Answer (score 0):

Observation: your requirement looks like it matches the map / reduce pattern.

If the values in your `ids` collection returned by `thirdpartylib.Methodforid()` are reasonably dense, and the number of rows in the table behind your `proc_name` stored procedure has close to the same number of items in the `ids` collection, you can retrieve all the records you need with a single SQL query (and a many-row result set) rather than retrieving them one by one. That might look something like this:

```
public static TestResponse PerformStuff()
{
    var response = new TestResponse();

    var idHash = new HashSet<int> (thirdpartylib.Methodforid());

    SqlCommand cmd = DB.GetSqlCommand("proc_name_for_all_ids");
    using (SqlDataReader dr = new SqlDataReader(DB.GetDataReader(cmd)) { 
        while (dr.Read()) {
            var id = dr.GetInt32("id");
            if (idHash.Contains(id)) {
                testReq = new TestRequest();

                testReq.col1 = dr.GetInt32("col1");
                testReq.col2 = dr.GetBoolean("col2");
                testReq.col3 = dr.GetString("col3");
                testReq.col4 = dr.GetBoolean("col4");
                testReq.col5 = dr.GetString("col5");
                testReq.col6 = dr.GetBoolean("col6");
                testReq.col7 = dr.GetString("col7");

                var output = thirdpartylib.MethodforResponse(request);
                foreach (var data in output.Elements())  {
                    response.col4 = Convert.ToInt32(data.Id().Class());
                    response.col2 = data.Id().Name().ToString();
                }
            } /* end if hash.Contains(id) */  
        }  /* end while dr.Read() */
    } /* end using() */
    return response;
}
```

Why might this be faster?  It makes many fewer database queries, and instead streams in the multiple rows of data to process.  This will be far more efficient than your example.

Why might it not work?

1. if the `id` values must be processed in the same order produced by `thirdpartylib.Methodforid()` it won't work.
2. if there's no way to retrieve all the rows, that is no `proc_name_for_all_ids` stored procedure available, you won't be able to stream the rows.